# Looping through data array properties in VueJS

Tags: vue-component, vue.js, vuejs2

In vuejs you can do list rendering in the template like

```
<td v-for="item in items"></td>......
```

But can you iterate over that same data array property like....

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++)
 this.$data.items[i]
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. If `items` is an array, of course, you can iterate over it, but `this.$data.items[i]` should be `this.items[i]`.

Comment: Please add more details, on what are you trying to do, what error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes

Just don't worry about the `this.$data.items`, instead `this.items`, although it would also work ...

Answer (score 2):

this post is quite old, but this can be useful to anyone who wants to iterate into an array of object.

Instead of:

```
for(var i =0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
  console.log(this.items[i]);
}
```

You can do this a little bit more concisely and more readable (in my opinion):

```
this.items.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item);
})
```