# How do I pass a list of objects from controller to view?

Tags: c#, list, vue.js, model-view-controller, datacontract

I have some data (a list of datacontracts) in my controller. I want to show the fields/ values of that list inside my view. How do I do this properly?

This is the code inside my controller where I get the list data:

```
public List<ShipmentDataContract> Get(long shipmentServiceId)
        {
            Logging.Instance.Info($"Shipment request came in for shipment with ShipmentServiceId = {shipmentServiceId}");
            ShipmentQueryResult shipmentQueryResult = GetShipmentByShipmentServiceIdResult(shipmentServiceId);
            Logging.Instance.Debug($"Shipment queried with ShipmentServiceId = {shipmentServiceId}");
            List<ShipmentDataContract> shipmentDataContracts = GetShipmentsFromResult(shipmentQueryResult);
            Logging.Instance.Info($"Shipment retrieved for shipment with ShipmentServiceId = {shipmentServiceId}.");
            return shipmentDataContracts;
        }
```

This method returns a list of datacontracts (only one in this case).

I made a test method inside the same controller as well within the Index method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var shipmentDataTest = Get(94);

            ViewBag.shipmentTestData = shipmentDataTest;

            return View();
        }
```

When I debug the backend, it returns the right shipment (with ID 94).

Now I want to show the shipment information within my view.

I made a variabele in my view:

```
<script>
    var shipmentTestData = '@ViewBag.shipmentTestData';
</script>
```

And within my Vue app file assigned the right values:

```
var Vue = new Vue({
    el: "#vueapp",
    components: ["error"],
    data: {
        shipmentTestData: shipmentTestData
    }
});
```

Than when I call the data, it will not show the values, but a generic string.

```
<p>{{ shipmentTestData }}</p>
```

It returns this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ShipmentDataContract]
```

Does someone know how to get this fixed? For some reason the variable that I assign is of format string which causes this issue I assume but how can I fix this?

Comment: It's this line right here `var shipmentTestData = '@ViewBag.shipmentTestData';` You are setting the `shipmentTestData` var to the List you are returning, then you try to use it as a string, so you get the `.ToString()` value of your List, which is it's type. If you want to display the items inside your list you need to iterate them and display the properties in the View.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply. I noticed that, but how do I do this? Since I am using razor to display it in the view. Can't find a way to implement this...

Comment: You could just skip setting it to a javascript variable and iterate the list using Razor inside your view and populate your HTML. This post shows how to use `Razor` and `ViewBag` together (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508961/how-to-loop-through-two-viewbag-items-on-view-pages-in-mvc-4-0)

Comment: But then I can;t access it right? Can you provide me with an example code snippet?

Comment: What do you mean, can't access it?? What is it you are trying to accomplish other than showing this data to the user?

Comment: I only want to show it to the user, but can't get it to work without setting the variabele. How would you do this?

Comment: I added a link above which shows how to iterate a list that belongs to the ViewBag

Comment: I see, but ViewBag is not defined in my view when I try that

Comment: Then how does this ever work? `var shipmentTestData = '@ViewBag.shipmentTestData';`

Comment: Thats in my index file, I need to display it within my template file

Comment: Should have specified that. Then you would need to iterate the `shipmentTestData` property of your Vue data. Try this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864494/looping-through-data-array-properties-in-vuejs)

Comment: Yes but that is a string, so if i iterate over that one it will iterate over every letter of the string instead of every object in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper way.

Model:

```
   public class ShipmentData
   {
       Task<List<ShipmentDataContract>> Get(long shipmentServiceId)
       {
          return YourList;
       }
```

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var shipmentDataTest = ShipmentData.Get(//index);

        return View(shipmentDataTest);
    }
```

View:

```
    @Model YourShipmentModel
    //here you can call Model.variable
```

Comment: But this solution does not work for me because I need to load the data within the template file, instead of in the main view file. I am able to load the data there, and works fine. But the template file is the problem here

Comment: Are you sure you are returning it right? it shows  `return shipmentDataContracts;` in your `Get` function. Shouldn't it be  `return shipmentDataContracts[shipmentServiceId];` if you want to return a specific object? else you will get what you described, a list.

Comment: It needs to be a list yes.. Returning a single one does not work either. The problem is that I can only load the objects within the list in the main view file, and not in the template file.. I am looking for a way to get the full object that the Get method returns inside my view for use.. Rightr now I have a string which  is the wrong data type

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the list as string you can send the result like

```
 IList<string> someStrings = Get(94); // i assume than get method returns a list of "strings"
 string joined = string.Join(",", someStrings );
 ViewBag.shipmentTestData = joined;
```

Now you are sending to frotend the list "shipmentDataTest" as a comma separated list.
Let me know if this is what you are looking for. Greetings.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply. I am actually getting a list of data contracts. So a list of objects

Comment: then you can try JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataContracts), and return a json string to manipulate with javascript in the cshtml.  for this JsonConvert  method i use Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3